# Scrollable TV Guide with HTML/XML/XSLT/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, xslt, television

I am trying to create a TV guide, similar to most already out there (http://www.freeview.co.uk/whats-on/tv-guide) - in that when you click next it displays the next x number of hours. Problem is, I have got the hours scrolling ok but the listings below are not scrolling with them after hours of playing about with it.

I have used the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stfzy/1136/. I currently have the scroller set up in the HTML file and the listings being displayed in the XSL file.

I need the entire grid to scroll on next/prev button click instead of just the time. I am using DIVs to store the times and programs etc.

Prev| 9am | 10am | 11am | 12am | 1pm | 2pm |Next

```
   |show|show|show|show|show|show
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.